# IIS ASAPI redirector Entity Too Large

Tags: iis, tomcat, redirect

I currently have IIS 6 running on a windows 2003 server, we are using iis with the asapi redirector which passes off to Tomcat. The problem we are running into is that I am getting a Request Entity Too large 413 error. We are not using SSL, but we do transmit headers from our single sign on solution. When a user access this site if they are authenticated it redirects them to our login page. This page is protected via a SSL cert. We pass information such as name, memberof etc in our headers so programs can determine security and display profile information. I have tried increasing the uploadReadAheadSize to insane amounts like 1-5MB and it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon what version of the IIS Tomcat Connector and Tomcat you are using, you may be able to set the max_packet_size to a value higher than the default to resolve this. The [Workers Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) has details on the max value for this parameter and the change you need to make on your Tomcat instance.